# Remove section number ToC entries with tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I have formatted a ToC with `tocloft` package. I have it almost right, but I would like to remove the numbers of the sections; just leave the section names.
I am trying different commands but I can not find the right one.
The problem is to maintain the number in the section themselves at the same time.

Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) inserts `\cftsecpresnum` *before* placing the section number, and `\cftsecaftersnum` *after* it. These are hooks you can use to tie into and grab the number:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{\end{lrbox}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Last section}
\end{document}
```

We effective wrap the numbering mechanism of `\section` within the ToC inside a box `\@tempboxa` and store it, but never use it again. This gobbles the contents.

Note that this redefinition is global in terms of the section number display. It can be made local if you only want to display specific parts with/without section numbers. It also maintains the numbering width (set by `\cftsecnumwidth`). If this should be removed, add

```
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{0pt}
```

to the document preamble as well.

Comment: I have a question: you already deleted the numbers in the contents table, but when you create the sections, the numbers still appear, is there a way to erase the numbers leaving just the title of the section?

Comment: Should this approach work as well for the `memoir` class instead of the `book` class? I keep getting the following when trying to compile my document: `! LaTeX Error: \cftsecpresnum undefined.` I can't just switch over to `book` based on how the rest of my document is structured (for the `memoir` class). I thought it worth asking here in case you knew before asking a separate question that is essentially the same one as OP's. (I looked at the `tocloft` package documentation but didn't really see anything there to fix my problem.)

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow: [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) uses `section` not `sec` for ToC-entries related to `\section`. See Table 9.3 of the [`memoir` user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) (p 150). Therefore, using `\cftsectionpresnum` and `\cftsectionaftersnum` works. Remember to remove the [`usepackage{tocloft}`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) as `memoir` provides this/similar functionality.

Comment: @Werner Thanks so much for your response (saved me a lot of head scratching). Tried it out and it worked perfectly. Thanks again!