# how to align page numbers in the toc when parts entries are centered and others are left aligned?

Tags: tocstyle

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} %{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{part}{}{\protect\parbox{\textwidth}{\protect\centering#2}\vspace{3ex}}
} % center the parts entries in the toc and add a 3ex vspace after
\settocstylefeature[-1]{entryvskip}{5ex} % add a 5ex vspace before parts entries in the toc

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{part 1}
\section{section 1}
\section{section 2}
\part{part 2}
\section{section 1}
\section{section 2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What you have done here is not center format the title; you have made the title a big box that is forcefully the full width of the page that happens to have the title centered in it. Of course the page number has no where left to go (also the dot separator is not removed, there just isn't room for it). You should start over and figure out how to actually format the title without the large box hack.

Comment: Without a parbox, multiple lines entries are centered only for their first line, and others are left aligned. This is not desirable. `\addtocentrydefault{part}{}{\hfil#2\hfil\vspace{3ex}}`

Comment: Aaa, I had not considered a part title that would be long enough to wrap. That would require a more  complex solution than [the one I came up with](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180107/5100). I still wonder if the parbox isn't a hack, but I can see the problem it's trying to fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things can get really ugly!

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} %{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{part}{}{\protect\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-1.55em\relax}{\protect\centering#2}\vspace{3ex}}
} % center the parts entries in the toc and add a 3ex vspace after
\settocstylefeature[-1]{entryvskip}{5ex} % add a 5ex vspace before parts entries in the toc

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{part 1}
\section{section 1}
\section{section 2}
\part{part 2}
\section{section 1}
\section{section 2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have simply reduced the width of the `\parbox` by `1.55em`.

Comment: Thanks Harish Kumar. Two questions: 1) Can it be achieved without the parbox? 2) Why do you add a `\relax`?

Comment: @lalebarde `\parbox` is needed. And `\relax` indicates the end of `\dimexpr`ession.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done here is not center format the title; you have made the title a big box that is forcefully the full width of the page that happens to have the title centered in it. Of course the page number has no where left to go (also the dot separator is not removed, there just isn't room for it).

Here is a solution using `tocloft` instead of `tocstyle` to format the entry (adapted from the [tocloft manual](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex2e/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf)). This allows for much cleaner formatting rules without hacking a big box into the flow. The only remaining problem was removing the automatic numbering which your example duplicates. I used a hack for that taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71136/5100). I suspect what you actually want to to is redo your numbering system so that latex inserts the correct numbers in the connect place for you rather then hand-number your parts, but that should be for another question.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\vskip 5ex\hfill\vspace{3ex}}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}}
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{\end{lrbox}\hfill}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{part 1}
\section{section 1}
\section{section 2}
\part{part 2}
\section{section 1}
\section{section 2}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: MWE output]

Comment: I have tested your solution with a very long part entry that wraps. I confirm you only the first line is centered, and the other is left aligned.